# How to set "value" to input web element using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have element in my code that looks like this:

```
<input id="invoice_supplier_id" name="invoice[supplier_id]" type="hidden" value="">
```

I want to set its value, so I created a web element with it's xpath:

```
 val test = driver.findElements(By.xpath("""//*[@id="invoice_supplier_id"]"""))
```

but now I dont see an option to set the value...

Comment: If you're working with an ID, you should use the appropriate By-Locator: `By.id("invoice_supplier_id")`

Comment: You are currently collecting a list of WebElements.  You will need to extract the WebElement from the list, or just find the WebElement by itself.  You will also need to unhide the element before Selenium can interact with it.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use `findElement` instead of `findElements`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='invoice_supplier_id'])).sendKeys("your value");
```

**OR**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("invoice_supplier_id")).sendKeys("value", "your value");
```

**OR using JavascriptExecutor**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("enter the xpath here")); // you can use any locator
 JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='enter the value here';", element);
```

**OR**

```
(JavascriptExecutor) driver.executeScript("document.evaluate(xpathExpresion, document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML="+ DesiredText);
```

**OR (in javascript)**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='invoice_supplier_id'])).setAttribute("value", "your value")
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Send keys to a hidden element?

Comment: I am getting same problem here. But there is no such `setAttribute` method in WebElement. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: @NarayanSubedi, the sendKeys method is working to me    driver.findElement(By.id("elementId")).sendKeys("value", "new value");

Comment: try using send_keys in place of sendKeys

Comment: Anyone having problems with this method can try https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3387/set-attribute-of-an-element-using-webdriver-python

Comment: You have to use this in latest versions ```driver.find_element_by_id("invoice_supplier_id").send_keys("your value")```

Answer (score 4):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("invoice_supplier_id")).setAttribute("value", "your value");
```

Comment: `findElement()` returns a `WebElement`.  `WebElement` does not have a `setAttribute()` method.

Comment: @Nathan, how about element.__setattr____("value", "your value")?

Comment: There is not setAttribute method available.

Answer (score 2):

As Shubham Jain stated, this is working to me: `driver.findElement(By.id("invoice_supplier_id")).sendKeys("value"‌​, "new value");`