# setAttribute() method for WebElement

Tags: java, c#, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35127108/5168011) both answers used `setAttribute()` as `WebElement` functionality. However, I couldn't find this method in the [Java](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html), [C#](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement.htm) nor [Python](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html) documentation, only `getAttribute()`. Trying to call this method from `WebElement` object in C# (Visual Studio) and Java (Eclipse) with the latest `Selenium` version produced the same results.

So my question is, does this method really exist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After inspecting the selenium Python [API docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html) and the [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/py), I can conclude - there is no such a method. And, there is nothing about it inside the [WebDriver specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html) itself.

To set an attribute, usually *a script is executed*:

```
elm = driver.find_element_by_id("myid")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1], arguments[2]);", 
                      elm,  
                      "attr_name",
                      "attr_value")
```

Comment: I agree, I couldn't find it either. But two different people gave this answer so I started wondering...

Comment: @guy yeah, I suspect these people are simply wrong. But, good finding.

Comment: Thank you, it take me a lot of try, about 5 hour, and this line help me out

Answer (score 6):

They are using the JavascriptExecutor class.

I.e.

```
WebDriver driver; // Assigned elsewhere
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('//id of element').setAttribute('attr', '10')");
```

Or an Extension Method

```
public static void setAttribute(this IWebElement element, string value, bool clearFirst)
{
    if (clearFirst) element.Clear();
    element.SendKeys(value);
}
```

Comment: No they are not, they are using this `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id="invoice_supplier_id"])).setAttribute("value", "your value")`

Comment: Nothing I could find.

Comment: I mean you could easily create an extension method that executes the javascript via the xpath or Id or sendkeys to the element. Look at what I editted with.

Comment: Yes, you could easily create this method. However, they didn't show JavaScript implementation, they used it as `WebElement` method. They chained this method to `driver.findElement()`, which return `WebElement`.

Comment: Which is why I am led to believe that it is similar to the extension method I posted.

Comment: If you really want to be able to set the properties of your htmlcontrols .NET's CodedUI Framework allows you to access them and change them.

Comment: I will look into it. But they didn't mention any changes in the html controls, they simply called the method as it was part of `WebElement` API.