# Text is not correctly typed in on Chrome/Ubuntu

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am running Selenium tests on Chrome browser which on Linux machine with following details -

```
Linux version - Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Chrome Version - 79.0.3945.79
Linux Chromedriver - 79.0.3945.36 (https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/)
```

In some of the text input fields like following code snippet, I'm typing in like - `http://www.example.com/pqr/xyz` using `sendKeys()` method

```
<input type="text" id="drvUrl" name="Driver URL" placeholder="JDBC URL for the source database system" required="" class="k-textbox eq-widget k-invalid" aria-invalid="true">
```

But url is typed without special characters like `httpwwwexamplecompqrxyz`. All special characters are removed.

I've got work-around where first I type in url using `JavascriptExecutor` but that is not ideal way to automate it.

Is there better workaround for this? Also I could not find similar bug on Selenium WebDriver, in that case, just wanted to confirm before logging bug there.

Answer (score 0):

if it has attribute called value, you can try to do as below.

driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).setAttribute("value", "your value");

[How to set "value" to input web element using selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127108/how-to-set-value-to-input-web-element-using-selenium/35127217)

Cheers!